# Installed XAMPP but can't connect to MYSQL server in cmd

Tags: php, mysql

First, MYSQL services is running in XAMPP
and, YES, I changed the port since it conflicts with other applications
Now, the question is why can't i connect to MYSQL?

Error 2003: Cant connect to MYSQL server on 'localhost'

I also dont have any mysql services installed.

Please help. Thank you for those people who would answer me :)

Comment: Try adding PATH variables.

Comment: yes server is working and its just a localhost

Answer (score 1):

First,make sure mysqld is running.

```
ps -ef |grep mysql
```

Second,get the socket file in the output of last command:

```
for example:--socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Then,try to connect to mysql:

```
mysql -uroot -p -P<port> -hlocalhost -S /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

option 1.

1. Goto /bin/
2. Run mysqld (service)
3. close the cmd prompt
4. Run mysql.exe (make sure you add the location path to PATH environment Variable)

Option 2.
try to follow this thread and see if it can help!!
http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/error-2003-cant-connect-mysql-server-localhost-10061-a-26423.html

Answer (score 1):

Run mysql.exe (make sure you add the location path to PATH environment Variable)

I would to know where is PATH enviroment variable